# Iterating through a 2D vector using one use case of for loop gives segmentation fault

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, 2d-vector

I needed to write a simple method that calculates the highest element in a matrix data (implemented in this case using a 2D vector). Inside the method, initially, I was accessing each element in the 2D vector using the one form (the most common one) of *for* loop which gave a **"segmentation fault"**. Unfortunately, I could not find a good reason that it should happen. Eventually, I resolved the issue using *for* loop in a different manner. However, I would still like to know the cause for the **"segmentation fault"** in the initial us case of *for* loop. I believe it is also a correct method to iterate through a 2D vector. Can someone explain the reason for this? Thanks in advance!

Initial(giving the error):

```
class customers {
public:
    int maximumWealth(vector<vector<int>>& accounts) {
        int richest_customer_wealth = 0;
        int sum;
        for(int i=0;i<accounts.size();++i){
            sum = 0;
            for(int j=0;i<accounts[i].size();++j){
                sum += accounts[i][j];
            }
            if(sum > richest_customer_wealth)
                    richest_customer_wealth = sum;
        }
        return richest_customer_wealth;
    }
};
```

After modifying the for loop:

```
class customers{
public:
    int maximumWealth(vector<vector<int>>& accounts) {
        int richest_customer_wealth = 0;
        int sum;
        for(vector<int> row: accounts){
            sum = 0;
            for(int val: row){
                sum += val;
            }
            if(sum > richest_customer_wealth)
                    richest_customer_wealth = sum;
        }
        return richest_customer_wealth;
    }
};
```

Comment: `sum_ij` looks used without declaration here.

Comment: @MikeCAT No! that was actually a typo while pasting the code snippet, I just corrected it. It's not the cause and should not be since it would not lead to a segmentation fault anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe it may be because in the inner loop you have

```
for(int j=0;i<accounts[i].size();++j)
```

when it should be

```
for(int j=0;j<accounts[i].size();++j){
```

Comment: Yes, you are right!...the fact that it was only because of a stupid typo ;) and I myself feel stupid now. Thanks anyway! I am closing the question now.